# How to make states from the keys of state object in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

So I was trying to implement states in Child component from the Parent component state,as you can see in the code.But it gives me undefined as state value in child componenet.To test you can conosle.log(questions) and you will see undefined.
Is there a mechanism to setState in Parent component in some way such that the subsequent props in child components wil be able to get the state values?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import io from "socket.io-client";
    const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";
    let socket = io(ENDPOINT);
    
    export default function Screen() {
    
      const [qValue, setQuestion] = useState({personalInfo:{},questions:[]});
      const [aValue, setAnswer] = useState({personalInfo:{},answer:""});
    
      useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("screenAns", (input) => {
          setAnswer(JSON.parse(input));
        });
        console.log(aValue);
      }, [aValue]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        socket.on("screenQs", (arrayValue) => {
          setQuestion(JSON.parse(arrayValue));
        });
        console.log((qValue));
      }, [qValue]);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Screen</h2>
          <QuestionSingleMode value={qValue} /> 
        </div>
      );
    }
    function QuestionSingleMode(props){
     
      var [questions,setQuestions]=useState(props.value.questions);
      var [renderQuestion,setRenderQuestion]=useState("")
      var [counter,setCounter]=useState(props.value.questions.length)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
     console.log(questions)
      setRenderQuestion(questions[0])
    },[renderQuestion])
      
      
     function nextQuestion(){
      setQuestions(questions.splice(0,1))
      setRenderQuestion(questions[0])
      setCounter(counter--)
    }
    
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>{renderQuestion}</h1>
          <button onClick={nextQuestion}>{counter ? "next" : "finish"}</button>
          
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved the issue by changing the **renderQuestion** to **props.questions** in the **useEffect()** array.